# how to get tax amount of a product in success page?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I want to get tax amount of a product in success page. I'm getting price of a product but not tax amount from order object. can anyone please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData('tax_amount')
```

in your checkout success page.

Hope this helps.

**update**

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();

$items = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')->load($orderId);
foreach($items as $item){
   echo '<pre>'.$item->getName() . ' ' . $item->getTaxAmount().'<pre>';
}
```

Note: I haven't tested it but should work.

Comment: I don't want total amount of the order. I want the individual product tax amount. Thanks

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: why does magento make you go through shipping address in order to get the tax amount. isn't this terrible api design and violation of all kinds of code design principles?